# How to reset error message in TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I know this is a simple question but i did not find how to do this. How can i reset error message in TextFormField when the user input something in the field. Something like onchange listener. I notice onChanged is available in TextField but not TextFormField. How can i do this?

```
final _email = Container(
  child: TextFormField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: email),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    controller: emailController,
    validator: _validateEmail,
    onSaved: (input) => _stringEmail = input.toLowerCase().trim(),
  ),
);
```

UPDATE: I am using controller to add listener for user input. But i just want to reset the error message instead of validating the form again. Is this possible? How can i do this?

```
  _resetEmailErrorMessage() {
    print("Second text field: ${emailController.text}");
    //replace clear to something that can reset the validation error message
    emailController.clear();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //start listening to changes
    emailController.addListener(_resetEmailErrorMessage);
  }
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use auto-validation feature of `Form`

If you looking for this solution,

> "As soon as you type it validates your input and show/hide error"

Flutter provides auto-validation feature, you just need to enable it at form level.

1. Default

   `_autoValidate = false;`
2. Form

```dart
    body: Form( key: _formKey,
                autovalidate: _autoValidate,....)
```

3. Enable it when user presses submit once,

```dart
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      // All Good
    } else {
      // start auto validate
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
```

### **Update :-**

Now `Form.autovalidate` is deprecated. So Use

```
Form.autovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
```

Comment: This does indeed solve the problem. Validating the form again resets the error messages for the fields that are now correct.

Comment: This is a good solution, but keep in mind that `autoValidate` has been deprecated and you should use `AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` instead.

Comment: add autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always to Form - works for me!

Answer (score 8):

`Form.autovalidate` has been deprecated. Use `Form.autovalidateMode = AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` to have the errors automatically clear once a user begins to interact with the form field again without having to manage any state yourself.

Comment: yeah, thanks bro, this new properties is just what we need :)

Answer (score 1):

The TextFormField also has the option of onChanged in that you can try to reset the form validation through the FormKey

```
final _email = Container(
 child: TextFormField(
 decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: email),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
  controller: emailController,
  validator: _validateEmail,
  onChanged: (value){
    formKey.currentState.reset();
  },
  onSaved: (input) => _stringEmail = 
   input.toLowerCase().trim(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: `reset` method clears `all` errorneous text fields but only one is changed must be used

Comment: if you want to clear the error warnings then you have to reset the form validation, I guess for now there is no other way

Answer (score 1):

```dart
// Somewhere in `State` declaration 
final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
bool autovalidate = false;

@override
void build(BuildContext context) {
  return Form(
    key: formKey,
    autovalidate: autovalidate,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        TextFormField(
          ...
          validator: (value) {
            return (value == null || value.isEmpty) ? 'Cannot be empty' : null;
          }
          onChanged: (value) {
            // Call this to refresh autovalidation result
            setState(() {});
          }
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

void validate() {
  if(formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    // data is valid!
    return true;
  } elsee {
    // Activate autovalidation
    autovalidate = true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the controller and listen to the User input . and whenever  he types something you can validate() your form again

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I have followed your advice. But i am not sure how to reset the validation error message in TextFormField. Please help

Comment: Instead of validating the form again, i just want the textformfield that has error showing to be reset again(clear the error). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible . I would suggest  for the function validate email to do ur logic  and tests . and if there is no problemes return null . and always validate the form field whenever he types something  and you should be okay

Comment: String validateEmail(String value) {
  
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "too long";
    } 
    return null;
  }

  TextFormField( validator: validateEmail ),

Comment: can't we do something like "emailController.validate()" or "emailController.resetError()" instead of validating the entire form?

Comment: You cant since the TextFormField is within form so you need to validate the form  to trigger the condition

Answer (score 0):

This one worked form. You can try to validate form like this:

```
_formKey.currentState.validate()
```

You need to define validate field in your `TextFormField`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any answers to your question. I also ran into a situation like this I wanted the fields of the authentication form to reset their validation error once the user changes to Login or Signup. So I added this logic:

```
class _AuthFormState extends State<AuthForm> {
...
  var _formFlipped = false;                                   // THIS RIGHT HERE

  void _trySubmit() {
    final isValid = _formKey.currentState.validate();
    FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return 
      ...
            child: Form(
                ...
                  TextFormField(
                    key: ValueKey('email'),
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (_formFlipped) return null;          // THIS
                      if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                        return 'Enter a valid email';
                      }
                      return null;
                    },
                    ...
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text(_isLogin ? 'Login' : 'Signup'),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _formFlipped = false;               // AND THIS
                        });
                        _trySubmit();
                      },
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text(_isLogin
                          ? 'Create new account'
                          : 'I already have an account'),
                      onPressed: () {                         // THIS TOO
                        setState(() {
                          _isLogin = !_isLogin;
                          _formFlipped = true;
                          _formKey.currentState.validate();
                        });
                      },
                    ),
        ...
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sZ5G.jpg) & [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJUJL.jpg).

Edit:

So basically you just force pass `null` on all your field validators to clear the message. Alternatively as [Yogesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12803789/yogesh-chawla) pointed out you can achieve this by simply `_formKey.currentState.reset();`

But if you need more granular control, this method serves you good since you can set `if (_formFlipped) return null;` or similar condition to different fields according to your need.